# Getting a bundle state via script from Karaf 3.0.5

Tags: apache-karaf, karaf, apache-servicemix

I can check a bundle state from Karaf Console by doing:-

```
karaf@root>bundle:list | grep camel-test
246 | Active |  50 | 2.16.1                             | camel-test
```

Is there a way I can do this programatically via some script running on the same machine as Karaf or via some REST End Point that Karaf exposes?

I am using Karaf 3.0.5 running under ServiceMix 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in [Karaf User Forum](http://karaf.922171.n3.nabble.com/Getting-a-bundle-state-via-script-from-Karaf-3-0-5-td4045740.html) I am able to achieve it using the karaf client:-

```
jabong@jabong1143:~/Downloads/apache-servicemix-6.1.0/bin$ ./client -l 0 -u karaf "bundle:list" | grep camel-test
246 | Active |  50 | 2.16.1                             | camel-test
```